# How to protect the ADC GPIO PIN [Battery monitor] from reverse polarity?

Tags: power-supply, analog, adc, battery-operated, reverse-polarity

I have a circuit which uses a battery boost converter to power the MCU.  I use the ADC on the MCU to measure the actual battery voltage to display how much charge is left in the battery.

The power side is protected from reverse polarity since the boost converter won't power up if the batteries are inserted backwards.

The ADC PIN of the un-powered MCU, however, will see negative -3 Volts between VBAT and GND. MCU pins handle -0.3V max, not -3V.

Adding additional components either mess up the measuring of the battery voltage or in the case of a reverse protection diode possibly short the batteries (not user friendly).

What's the solution here? Pretty sure I'm not the first person with this issue.  How is this commonly dealt with?

thanks!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnO6w6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Moderate series resistor and diode clamps to the rails?   The MCU may already have those, if you're lucky they have a published injection current limit you can compare to the resistor.

Comment: Put a resistor R between battery and MCU's ADC PIN and make it as large as you can get away with: not so large that the input current of the MCU pin causes a significant voltage drop across R, but big enough to limit battery current drain when off (current through R and the clamp diode of the MCU). If current drain when off is still unacceptably high then put in an active switch to enable reading of battery.

Comment: @ChrisStratton could you turn the comment into an answer?  I'm curious what the diode clamps will look like.

Comment: @td127 wouldn't an active switch have a voltage drop?  and in that case, why not just use a diode and adjust for the voltage drop?

Comment: How about an ideal diode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MCU input pin has (presumably) protection diodes to both ground and VCC. It’s the diode to VCC that can become a problem when unpowered because the 3V at the MCU pin now has a path through that diode to the VCC net which almost assuredly has a residual path to ground (through the MCU, other unpowered chips, passive networks from VCC to ground, etc.)

If that residual resistance is small it might destroy the MCU pin by exceeding its current rating. If it’s large enough it won’t hurt the MCU but will still be a load on the battery when off, which is not desirable.

Putting a series diode between battery and MCU would protect the MCU against a battery plugged in backwards but do nothing to protect again unwanted current flow during power off (path now being through two diodes instead of one).

An active switch from battery to MCU is probably best bet to solve these problems. The most straightforward approach may be a MOSFET in series:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKWKQr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The gate needs to be asserted high (by a GPIO from the MCU for example) to turn on the FET so the battery can be read. With power off, gate is low, Vgs = 0 and the FET is off.

If the battery can be inserted backwards, a series diode from the battery to the FET may be a good idea.

OOPS - As Chris Stratton pointed out, the single MOSFET won't work. You need two. The pulldown transistor could be a simple NPN:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpsR53.png)</sup>

But if all you really care about is protecting against a reversed battery (as your original post indicates) then a simple diode would work. With a Schottky diode (e.g. BAT54) and such a tiny current draw you would only lose a few tenths of a volt in the measurement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPBAhj.png)</sup>

Comment: How are you going to get a positive VGS (eg, a voltage *above* the supply input) to turn the gate of an enhancement-mode NFET on?  Typically this would be an application for a PFET, possibly enabled in turn by an NFET

Comment: Thanks Chris - I've edited the schematic to use two FETs. Look good now?

Comment: Much better in concept, but you need FET's with a lower threshold voltage such that they'll be "really" and not just "barely" on at 3 volts drive.

Comment: Thanks again. Replacing M1 with a standard NPN (resistor to base) will get rid of one of the fussy FETs. The P-chan MOSFET is unavoidable and will need to have a low Vgs.

Comment: @ChrisStratton to your point, this is what I had initially, but as the batteries ware down, 3V can get as low as 1.6V, barely ON and effectively change RdsOn.

Comment: @td127 thanks for the answer!

Comment: OK, but if the battery gets that low isn't it sufficient to tell the user "dude, your battery's dead, replace it", or do you really need an accurate reading down to 0V?

Comment: @td127 you're right. that's the whole idea for reading the voltage with ADC.  But it depends on your definition of "dead" :) the boost controller is happy as low as 0.8V with AAs in series. So it'd be nice to have a clean read at the very end of the bat life

Comment: Re-reading your original post, it seems like you were really only concerned with a battery installed backwards, not the leakage through unpowered pins. If that's all you're worried about then yes, a simple diode (schottky for minimal drop) from the battery to the MCU would suffice, working all the way down to a fraction of a volt. If that's the case, sorry for making this much more complicated than it needed to be!

Comment: @td127 Yes, boost controller will cut off 3.3 VCC but, the MCU pin connected to VBAT will go -3V which I'm pretty sure will blow the clamping diode on the PIN (if there is one). Another alternative I've heard of is a series res with a clamping diode.  Not sure which is better

Comment: I don't see why VBAT would ever appear as a negative voltage... how would that happen? (I mean, after you put the schottky in.)

Comment: @td127 well, technically it would GND that go -3V.  But if I'm reading your answer correctly, I still have to worry about "powering" the chip through the ADC pin if the Boost controller is off?  When the boost is off, it's line powered, but I'd worry about draining battery while line powered.

Comment: @MandoMando I see what you mean. While it's true that when power is off there's still 3V from the top of the battery to the GND net, that's no reason to redefine the GND net as -3V. GND stays GND and the battery stays at +3V. The battery drain problem is only when the power is off, because that's the only time the internal diode of the MCU (and there might be another in the booster IC) will conduct. (There are no problems when power is on.) Maybe battery drain is negligible and you just live with it. Brute force solution: use a relay.